# Convert SDP data from byte[] into Object?

Tags: java, android, byte, sdp

I am currently sending and receiving SIP messages across a network.

When I want to add SDP data to a SIP message I use the SessionDescription object in jrtp.

This object is then added to the SIP message.

But when I get a SIP message from the server its SDP is in a byte[] array.

So I'm wondering is there anyway to convert the byte[] back into a SessionDescription object so I can use the SessionDescription object's methods to parse the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Byte[] **wrapper**  class of byte.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how that would be utilised? At the minute I get the content back as the Byte[] but how do I convert that into a SessionDescription object?